# How do Helper T cells activate Cytotoxic T cells?

Tags: immunology, immunity

Helper T  cells activate the Antigen-presenting Cells (APCs) through their secretions (the cytokines) (although the T cell in question gets activated in turn). This is typically achieved by cell-to-cell contact using  receptors on both the helper T
cell and APC.
Since Helper T cells also activate Cytotoxic T
cells, I am particularly interested in knowing whether cell-to-cell contact occurs between these two T cell subtypes (as is the case in helper T cell - APC communication).

Comment: So, are you asking about whether there's physical contact between CD4+ and CD8+ T cells?

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, that is exactly what I'm asking